# Log4j2 with WAS 8.5

Tags: java

Is there any issue using Log4j2 in Websphere Application Server 8.5? I have a web app which is running fine in JBOSS and Tomcat and generating logs but same if I deploy in WAS logs are not generating. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Do you have any error stack trace ? Where is log4.properties file location ? It needs to be in the classpath for example on maven project it would be in src/main/resources/

Comment: No error stack trace. I am using log4j2.xml and the application is able to generate logs in Tomcat and JBOSS. But not in WAS.

Comment: I put my log4j2.xml in the resources folder and used it as source folder in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I expected your log4j2.xml is located in resource folder in your project.
And your pom.xml contains right artifact or log4j2 library are referenced correctly because when it run, it is fine under your IDE.

There is two options for you.

1. Add log4j2.xml to war. (Normally resource folder is include in classpath)
2. Add Option to command line. If you use Tomcat, create(or update) `setenv.sh` file.
   `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\log4j2.xml` (path can be different up to your environment.)